# How does Mesos-DNS name tasks with slash ("nested")?

Tags: dns, mesos, mesosphere

For example:

If Marathon is running a task named `/cassandra`, Mesos-DNS assigns it a DNS name - `cassandra.marathon.mesos`.

Now I have a task named `/monit/promdash`. **How can I find its DNS name?**

Already tried:

- `monit_promdash.marathon.mesos`, `promdash_monit.marathon.mesos` <del>(and with `-` instead of `_`)</del>, `monit.marathon.mesos`, `promdash.marathon.mesos`, ...)
- There's a [HTTP interface](https://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/http.html). Couldn't find how to list all DNS names either...

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marathon reverses the hierarchical names, concatenates them with `-` and this is the app name then, so in your case it would be `promdash-monit.marathon.mesos`. Try it out.

At the bottom of the [Mesos-DNS naming](http://mesosphere.github.io/mesos-dns/docs/naming.html) documentation we provide some more details about how these FQHN are constructed and you can also check out a [complete end-to-end example](https://mesosphere.com/blog/2015/06/21/web-application-analytics-using-docker-and-marathon/) I've put together, using two levels of hierarchies.

Comment: Happy to be of help ;)